# Necessary and sufficient condition isolated point.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $a \in A$. Prove that $a$ is an isolated point of $A$ if and only
if there exists an $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_\epsilon(a)$ such that $V_\epsilon(x) \cap A = \{a\}$.

I am not understanding if $V_\epsilon(x)$ is different from $V_\epsilon(a)$. Because $V_\epsilon(a)$ will always contain $a$. I am totally confused by this.

Comment: I think the $x$ is a typo. It should be $V_\epsilon(a)\cap A=\{a\}$. Indeed, $V_\epsilon(a)$ will always contain $a$. The assertion is that $a$ be the _only_ common element of the neighborhood with $A$.

Comment: I think this definition gives a perfect intuition for the isolatedness of a point: a point is isolated in $A$ if (informally) there aren't points of $A$ arbitrarily close to it, i.e., there is some punctured nbd of that point such that its intersection with $A$ is empty.

Comment: But first, let me ask, what definition of "isolated point" are you using in order to prove this equivalent definition?

Comment: I think I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if it is an typo, the definition of an isolated point is that isn't a limit point. So that means that we can find a neighborhood that doesn't contain any other elements from $A$. Hence the intersection $V_\epsilon(a) \cap A = {a}$